# How to get the UWP DisplayName property on PowerShell 7?

Tags: powershell

This code works perfectly on PowerShell 5.1 allowing to get localized names of all UWP apps.

```
$Packages = [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager,Windows.Web,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::new().FindPackages()
$Packages | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id -Property DisplayName | Format-Table -Property Name, DisplayName
```

On PowerShell 7 (7.1.1) it fails

```
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager,Windows.Web, ContentType=WindowsRuntime].
```

I googled about [findpackages class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages) but did't figure out how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Does this command give you want you're looking for?  Run as admin if you use the -AllUsers switch

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

Comment: Of course no. I know all about UWP cus I maintain very big GitHub repo but the question is only about how to make only this command work.